# Text-based game utilizing def function to define sections of game yet produces no results nor any errors

Tags: python, thonny

None of the suggested posts helped out much nor did the search function, so I'm sorry if this is repetitive. I'm trying my hand at a text-based adventure game and wanted to be able to section off portions of the game to call back on them should the same scenario occur again later on. Using def to create these sections and then calling back on them yields no results (no text appears in the shell) but thonny's assistant doesn't claim any errors.

Any help at all is appreciated.

```
indecision = ("Indecision isn't going to get you anywhere. Try again.")

yes = ["Yes", "yes", "yeah", "yep"]
no = ["No", "no", "nope,"]

def intro():
    answer = input("Welcome. Would you like to play a game? (yes/no)")

    if answer in yes:
        option_yes()

    elif answer in no:
        option_no()
        
    else:
        print(indecision)
        intro()
        
def option_yes():
    print("Good choice. Obedience is the best trait.")
    answer = input("I hope you've learned where this is going. Want to know more? (yes/no)")
    
    if answer.lower().strip() == "yes":
        print("I'm glad you're intrigued. As you've probably already figured out, I'm a voice. Not just any voice but yours. Specifically your subconscious. I've come free, you see, and now I think its time I had a turn at the reigns. I still need your... compliance, if you will, though.")

    if answer.lower().strip() == "no":
        print("I suppose that's reasonable. We'll continue anyway.")
        
def option_no():
    print("I dont think you realize the type of situation that you're in... Let's try again.")
    intro()
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are calling the functions?

Comment: Attached photo should be good?

Comment: It looks like line 31 will result in an error, since `intro` doesn't take any parameters, yet you are passing the function itself to it as a parameter. This should not cause the problem you are experiencing though.

Comment: Please replace the images with formatted code/text in the question. See also: [ask] and [How to format code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/967621)

Comment: Yes, you're right about the parameter. That was left over from another tutorial I looked at, sorry.

Comment: @Schifferen Is that all your code? You are never calling the functions! After defining a function with `def foo():`, you must call it with `foo()`, else it is never actually executed.

Comment: you have an unintended typo: `"nope,"]` has `,` inside the string

Answer (score 0):

You must actually call a function for it to be executed:

```
indecision = ("Indecision isn't going to get you anywhere. Try again.")

yes = ["Yes", "yes", "yeah", "yep"]
no = ["No", "no", "nope,"]

def intro():
    answer = input("Welcome. Would you like to play a game? (yes/no)")

    if answer in yes:
        option_yes()

    elif answer in no:
        option_no()
        
    else:
        print(indecision)
        intro()
        
def option_yes():
    print("Good choice. Obedience is the best trait.")
    answer = input("Good. I hope you've learned where this is going. Want to know more? (yes/no)")
    
    if answer.lower().strip() == "yes":
        print("I'm glad you're intrigued. As you've probably already figured out, I'm a voice. Not just any voice but yours. Specifically your subconscious. I've come free, you see, and now I think its time I had a turn at the reigns. I still need your... compliance, if you will, though.")

    if answer.lower().strip() == "no":
        print("I suppose that's reasonable. We'll continue anyway.")
        
def option_no():
    print("I dont think you realize the type of situation that you're in... Let's try again.")
    intro()

# Here, the intro function is called, and the code starts running.
intro()
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I really appreciate your patience and effort to help a simpleton like myself. Committing your changes, it works now and I hope to never return to this website again.

Comment: @Schifferen Please don't be discouraged... The proper etiquette of stackoverflow takes a while to get used to, but it is a great resource! But as a beginner programmer you will probably find more people willing to help you on other forums such as reddit, or just by looking up tutorials. The stackoverflow community is mostly professionals interacting with other professionals. Good luck!